# Access SQL- Count distinct months from Table 1 by City in Table 2

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table (Orders) featuring CustomerID, Product, Sales, and Date (yyyy-mm-dd).

CustomerID is linked to the Customer table at CustomerName. The Customer table has fields Customername, City, State, Country.

I would like to count the number of unique months for the calendar year which an ordered occurred by each City.

Unfortunately, so for I've only been able to count distinct months across all Customers and Dates. How can I tie it to each city in the Customer table?

```
SELECT Count(*) AS CountOfMonths
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT Month(Date), Year(Date)
FROM Orders );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select country, city, state,
       count(*) as NumDistinctMonths
from (select c.country, c.state, c.city,
             year(o.date) as yyyy, month(o.date) as mm, count(*) as cnt
      from orders as o inner join
           customers as c
           on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerId
      group by c.country, c.state, c.city, year(o.date), month(o.date)
     ) as ccsym
group by country, city, state;
```

Comment: it looks like this might have worked, i'm going to do some spot checks before I check it Answered. THanks on the interim!

Answer (score 0):

Simply join the tables and aggregate by year and city and count distinct months:

```
select c.country, c.state, c.city, year(o.date), count(distinct month(o.date))
from orders o
join customers c on c.customername = o.customerid
group by c.country, c.state, c.city, year(o.date)
order by c.country, c.state, c.city, year(o.date);
```

Add a `WHERE` clause, if you want to see one year only.

**UPDATE:** MS Access doesn't support `COUNT(DISTINCT expresssion)`. So you need a distinct subquery there:

```
select c.country, c.state, c.city, order_year, count(*)
from
(
  select distinct c.country, c.state, c.city, year(o.date) as order_year, month(o.date)
  from orders o
  join customers c on c.customername = o.customerid
) as dist_months
group by country, state, city, order_year
order by country, state, city, order_year;
```

Comment: for some reason i'm getting
 'syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'count(distinct month(o.date))'

Comment: Ah, one of the many drawbacks in MS Access I was not aware of. I've updated my answer accordingly.